Is my gas parameter being ignored?
I am trying to mint some tokens of an ERC20 contract using the function web3.eth.sendTransaction.
Currently, the gas fee exceeds my limit, so I set the gasLimit as a parameter. But when I set the gas limit, I get the error as:
insufficient funds for gas * price + value 

in which I see that the supplied gas is 600000000 while i entered the gas as follows:
web3.eth.sendTransaction({ gas: 37429 })

I had to set the gas limit because without that, it would throw the 'out of gas' error.

It would work fine if you just pass the gasPrice field and its value as await web3.eth.getGasPrice(), like:
web3.eth.sendTransaction({ gasPrice: await web3.eth.getGasPrice() });


The way you're passing the hardcoded gas value (e.g., 37429) could potentially lead to an 'out of gas' error because the specified gas might be less than what is required to execute the function.
Instead, you can estimate the required gas using the web3.eth.estimateGas function, like:
const gasEstimate = await web3.eth.estimateGas({
    from: walletAddress,
    to: tokenAddress,
    data: encodedMintTxData
});

So, the ideal code would be:
const encodedMintTxData = tokenContract.methods.mint(mintToAddress, amount).encodeABI();

const getGasEstimateForMintFunction = async () => {
    const gasEstimate = await web3.eth.estimateGas({
        from: walletAddress,
        to: tokenAddress,
        data: encodedMintTxData,
    });

    return gasEstimate;
}

const sendTransaction = async () => {
    const transaction = {
        from: walletAddress,
        to: tokenAddress,
        gas: await getGasEstimateForMintFunction(),
        gasPrice: await web3.eth.getGasPrice(),
        data: encodedMintTxData,
    };

    const signedTransaction = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(transaction, privateKey);
    const tx = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTransaction.rawTransaction);
    console.log("Transaction sent successfully. Transaction hash:", tx.transactionHash);
}

sendTransaction();

